# Batch to execute sql files

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

The requirement is to read the content of text file that contains .sql files to be exexcuted for example the file content will looks like

```
test.sql
test2.sql
```

I execute single sql file using

```
sqlcmd -S testserver -U xxx -P %Pwd% -d yyy -I -i "UDDs"\UDDs.sql >> _Deploy.txt
```

any idea how to loop on each line in the text file and execute it

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("fileList.txt") do (
    sqlcmd -S testserver -U xxx -P %Pwd% -d yyy -I -i "%%~fa" >> _Deploy.txt 
)
```

?

use [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to read file line by line.

Comment: While this may be a correct answer, it would really benefit from an explanation what this code does/how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be batch? Batch is dying. Quickly.

```
$filelist = get-content -path "filelist.txt";
foreach ($file in $filelist) {
    invoke-sqlcmd -serverinstance testserver -database zzz -username xxx -password yyy -inputfile $file| export-csv -notypeinformation -path $($file.replace("sql","csv"))
}
```

This is a PowerShell script which will loop through all the files named in your list of files, and output a CSV file (with the same "base" name) containing the data.

Comment: Batch is going nowhere. Look at how much more you have to type with powershell.

Comment: PowerShell is **the** way forward per Microsoft. Batch is around only for legacy reasons - people interested in getting things done in a modern way are leaving it in droves. As for "typing more" - use tab auto-completion is a thing, and the result is **readable code** instead of hieroglyphics.

Comment: Powershell isn't natively enabled, so it has to be turned on for every computer you want to deploy a PS script to. Tab completion isn't a thing in text editors (LOL if you're about to suggest an IDE for a scripting language). Powershell is just as readable as batch, but it's longer and more exhausting to both read and write. That said, I freely admit that PS is a better choice if you need to interact with GUIs or do math with numbers larger than 2^31, but I prefer batch because I don't have a typing fetish.

Comment: Powershell has NOTHING to do with GUIs (it's meant to be a GUI-less admin interface for Windows and software/hardware running on the platform). Tab completion exists on the command line and the built-in ISE is available anywhere PowerShell is and *quite* usable. It's installed by default on Win 7/2008R2 and higher, and immediately available for use (the "natively enabled" you refer to is the default execution policy, which is easily changed by GPO and has a less restrictive default on newer OSes).